# FetchObject() only return one result

Tags: 7, database

Select query will always return a result set object of one record.. There are several ways to then retrieve data from that result set, depending on the use case.

```
   user's flaged entity id:

  $query = db_select('flagging', 'f');
  $query->condition('f.uid', $data['uid'], '=');
  $query->fields('f', array('entity_id'));
  $result = $query->execute()->fetchObject();
```

and also used following query statements

```
         $query->__toString()

         SELECT f.entity_id AS entity_id  FROM {flagging} f WHERE  (f.uid = :db_condition_placeholder_0)
```

I replace the **db_condition_placeholder_0**  with specify uid.
It return me the right result (2 results).

```
   **$query->execute()->fetchAssoc()**`, return one result.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Drupal 7, there are fetch methods that can help to avoid loops like that. From [http://drupal.org/node/310072:](http://drupal.org/node/310072%3a)

```
<?php
  // Retrieve all records into an indexed array of stdClass bjects.
  $result->fetchAll();
 // Retrieve all records into an associative array keyed by the field in the result specified.
  $result->fetchAllAssoc($field);

  // Retrieve a 2-column result set as an associative array of field 1 => field 2.
  $result->fetchAllKeyed();
 // You can also specify which two fields to use by specifying the column numbers for each field
  $result->fetchAllKeyed(0,2); // would be field 0 => field 2
  $result->fetchAllKeyed(1,0); // would be field 1 => field 0

  // Retrieve a 1-column result set as one single array.
  $result->fetchCol();
  // Column number can be specified otherwise defaults to first column
  $result->fetchCol($column_index);
 ?>
```